# Error when running an installed WSL platform: WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install WSL2, but getting error above. Virtual Machine platform and Windows subsystem for linux are enabled, also kernel update installed. In BIOS intel virtualization is enabled. How to fix that?

Answer (score 9):

It's worth verifying the machine meets the hardware requirements.

Buried in the [WSL troublshooting page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting) under "Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS" the first item is to check [Hyper-V System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/system-requirements-for-hyper-v-on-windows#:%7E:text=on%20Windows%20Server.-,General%20requirements,the%20processor%20must%20have%20SLAT.).

WSL 2 uses a subset of Hyper-V for virtualization, so while you don't need Win 10 Pro, you do still need the hardware to be able to run Hyper-V.

At the time of writing, the docs say Hyper-V requires the following:

- 64-bit Processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
- CPU support for VM Monitor Mode Extension (VT-x on Intel CPU's).
- Minimum of 4 GB memory. As virtual machines share memory with the Hyper-V host, you will need to provide enough memory to handle the expected virtual workload.

A quick way to check requirements: run `msinfo32.exe` and under `System Summary` at the very bottom it notes the Hyper-V requirements:

[image: The MS info system summary section showing the Hyper-V items and values]

...in my case, I'm out of luck as my processor lacks SLAT.

Comment: thanks, for me it was "Virtualization Enabled in Firmware - No", which was easy to change in BIOS.

Comment: Mine already has Yes for all 4 of those, and I haven't found a `Limit CPUID Max` setting in my BIOS (as mentioned in another answer on this page).

Comment: I finally figured out how to get WSL 2 working (after months of effort)! https://askubuntu.com/a/1346121/48214

Comment: @Ryan I don’t know what issue you’re running into but if these are all checked then I don’t think hardware is the problem, which is all this answer addresses ;)

Comment: BTW, VirtualBox doesn't support nested virtual machines, so only VMWare can run it (example use case: docker for windows).

Answer (score 7):

The issue might be that **virtualisation is disabled** in you compute. To enable, follow these steps:

1. Open a **PowerShell** console as **Administrator**.
2. **Run** the following command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

**Ref**: Microsoft's enable Hyper-V [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

If still had this **error**, make sure **`hyper-V` in CPU is enabled**. For AMD CPUs, it's called SVM (in BIOS).

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: I would like to add that I had enabled Hyper-V throught the "Windows Componentes" GUI, and still faced the OP problem. Running this command solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in BIOS. You need to disable `Limit CPUID Max` to get it work.

Comment: Same problem, same error number, but my BIOS has no such setting, What then, or might it have another name?

Comment: @DonP try to disable and then enable Virtualization in BIOS

Comment: Just had look and there is nothing at all like that in my BIOS so maybe my PC and BIOS are too old as the BIOS is dated 2009 and is the latest that exists for this computer. It runs Ubuntu Studio very well but not WSL2.

Comment: @DonP yeah it can be also problem with sse4.1 or sse4.2, btw i do not exactly requirements of wsl2.

Comment: Mine already has Yes for all 4 of the features shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63270858/470749, and I haven't found a `Limit CPUID Max` setting in my BIOS. This has been driving me crazy for months. I'm really eager to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you're inside a Virtual Machine, your VM may not be setup to run nested VMs:

[Windows Nested Virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization)

Comment: I voted this answer up as it helped me solve the problem. To clarify I did run command "Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true" as admin user in the Power Shell of the host(!)-system. A restart of the the VM was also required.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the same situation as you.
SVM(VT) is enable and Hyper-V option is enable but Can't use WSL2.
My problem is rebooting problem. windows 10's reboot is not actual reboot.
WSL2 does not complete installed.
Try reboot with press shift key.

Comment: SVM needs to be enabled on AMD CPUs if anyone was wondering